# MakeFile em C++ - Geany

Tags: c++, makefile, geany

Boa tarde, sou novata no que toca a programar em C++ utilizando o Geany. E estou com dificuldade no que diz respeito a criar interligar uma classe com o main, isto é ao criar uma classe, por exemplo message.h e message.cpp aceder a métodos próprios da classe message no main.cpp.

Já vi tutoriais que explicam como criar um ficheiro Makefile, no entanto aparece-me o erro de que não foram criados targets.

O ficheiro Makefile que tenho é o seguinte:

```
output: main.o Language.o
    g++ main.o Language.o -o output

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp


Language.o: Language.cpp Language.h
    g++ -c Language.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o output
```

Se alguém tiver dicas de como "interligar" as classes e o main são bem-vindas.

Comment: `make output` deve gerar a saida. Se quiser que compile somente com `make` deve criar um target chamado `all` e colocar o `output` como dependência.

Comment: @ViniciusSouza já tentei com make e não deu